# Problem when opening a raster layer

Tags: qgis, raster

I am a news user with QGIS API C++. In order to feel good with it I try some little program to explore class.

I have download the tutorial 4 of the QGIS and adapted it to the 2.8 version but when I call the connect addlayer, I have an error message like layer is not valid.

Here is the code I use:

```
QString myRasterFileName = "SR_50M_alaska_nad.tif";
QString MyRasterPath = "/home/flodev/cartes/";

QString MyRaster = MyRasterPath + myRasterFileName;

QFileInfo myRasterFileInfo(MyRasterPath+myRasterFileName);

QString myBaseNameQString = myRasterFileInfo.baseName();

QgsRasterLayer * myRasterLayer = new QgsRasterLayer(MyRaster,myBaseNameQString);

qDebug() << "RasterLayer type =" << myRasterLayer->rasterType();

if (myRasterLayer->isValid())
{
  qDebug("Layer is valid");
}
else
{ 
  qDebug("Layer is NOT valid");
  return; 
}
```

I don't know what's wrong.
If you have any idea?
The raster file is the file given in the tutorial directory 
and code is adapted from tutorial4.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution :

you can use this code

```
QString myFileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"),
                       QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath () + "/data",
                       tr("GeoTiff (*.tif)"));

  QFileInfo myRasterFileInfo(myFileName);

  qDebug() << "myFileName =" << myFileName;


  QgsRasterLayer * myRasterLayer = new QgsRasterLayer(myRasterFileInfo.filePah(), 
      myRasterFileInfo.completeBaseName());
```

or this one

```
QString myRasterFileName = "Abarema_jupunba_projection.tif";

  QString MyRasterPath = "/home/flodev/semaport/cartes/";

  QString MyRaster = MyRasterPath + myRasterFileName;

  QFileInfo myRasterFileInfo(MyRaster);

  qDebug() << "myFileName =" << MyRaster;

  QgsRasterLayer * myRasterLayer = new  QgsRasterLayer(myRasterFileInfo.filePath(),myRasterFileInfo.completeBaseName());
```

I think that the error i have made in my code is the information passed into the function QgsRasterLayer

hope that it will be helpfull for other users

Answer (score 3):

In 4th line:

```
QString MyRaster = myRasterFileName + myRasterFileName;
```

Should be:

```
QString MyRaster = MyRasterPath + myRasterFileName;
```

Comment: oups, i have just made the correction but still not working, i have the same error message

Comment: does anyone can try to read the file .tif in the tutorial and tell me if they'll manage to read it as a raster, in qgis we can see the south of america in black,and withe, but the C++ sample said that the raster is not valid